# Cron job every three days

Tags: cron

Is it possible to run a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) every three days? Or maybe 10 times/month.

Comment: Yes it is possible and this belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: running every 3 days regardless of month boundaries can be done with anacron.

Comment: I think that CRON notation, while not technically a programming language, is complex enough that it's reasonable to ask here.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Run it every three days - or less at the end of the month. (It'll run 2 days in a row if the previous month had 31 days.)

```
0 0 */3 * *
```

How about that?

If you want it to run on specific days of the month, like the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc... then you can just have a conditional in your script that checks for the current day of the month.

```
if (((date('j') - 1) % 3))
   exit();
```

or, as @mario points out, you can use date('k') to get the day of the year instead of doing it based on the day of the month.

Comment: @whatshakin: It'll depend on how accurate you want "every three days" to be.  This will work on any day which is divisible by 3.  On month boundaries it won't be exact.

Comment: @whatshakin: The cronjob syntax is even described on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjob

Comment: This is a very high result on google, and as such it would be better if the accepted answer was correct, which this is not. I believe Tareco's explanation is correct.

Comment: Totally agreed.  What do we do in this sort of situation -- when an answer is really not correct?

Comment: @Bryan: I am curious to know why this answer is not correct?  My initial answer is to use cron syntax trigger a run every 3 days.  My addendum to that is to allow for business logic in the program to decide whether it should be run given a different criteria.  If this is not correct, please let me know so I can correct it for future readers.

Comment: The answer is not correct because neither suggestion actually runs the job every 3 days.  `0 0 */3 * *` means run on the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc. (`*/3` means `1-31/3` means `1,4,7...31`) so the gap will be smaller at the end of the month.  (It'll run 2 days in a row if the previous month had 31 days.)  The `date('j') % 3` has a similar problem in that the pattern restarts every year, and years don't have a number of days divisible by 3.

Comment: I too considerate it unfortunate that this was accepted as the answer. I really was looking for the every N days, regardless of month boundaries (things like plants don't care what day of the month they get their water). At least I think I determined after reading all of the comments, that the cron timer does not by itself fully model that desire.

Answer (score 86):

```
* * */3 * *  that says, every minute of every hour on every three days. 

0 0 */3 * *  says at 00:00 (midnight) every three days.
```

Comment: appreciate the explanation

Comment: This will usually fire every three days, but can fire on the next day at the beginning of a month

Answer (score 32):

Because cron is "stateless", it cannot accurately express "frequencies", only "patterns" which it (apparently) continuously matches against the current time.

Rephrasing your question makes this more obvious:   "is it possible to run a cronjob at 00:01am every night except skip nights when it had run within 2 nights?"  When cron is comparing the current time to job request time patterns, there's no way cron can know if it ran your job in the past.

(it certainly is possible to write a stateful cron that records past jobs and thus includes patterns for matching against this state, but that's not the standard cron included in most operating systems.  Such a system would get complicated by requiring the introduction of the concept of when such patterns "reset".  For example, is the pattern reset when the time is changed (i.e. the crontab entry is revised)?  Look to your favorite calendar app to see how complicated it can get to express Repeating patterns of scheduled events, and note that they don't have the reset problem because the starting calendar event has a natural "start" a/k/a "reset" date.   Try rescheduling an every-other-week recurring calendar event to postpone by a week, over christmas for example.  Usually you have to terminate that recurring event and restart a completely new one; this illustrates the limited expressivity of how even complicated calendar apps represent repeating patterns.  And of course Calendars have a lot of state-- each individual event can be deleted or rescheduled independently [in most calendar apps]).

Further, you probably want to do your job every 3rd night *if successful*, but if the last one failed, to try again immediately, perhaps the next night (not wait 3 more days) or even sooner, like an hour later (but stop retrying upon morning's arrival).  Clearly, cron couldn't possibly know if your job succeeded and the pattern can't also express an alternate more frequent "retry" schedule.

ANYWAY--
You can do what you want yourself.  Write a script, tell cron to run it nightly at 00:01am.  This script could check the timestamp of something* which records the "last run", and if it was >3 days ago**, perform the job and reset the "last run" timestamp.

(*that timestamped indicator is a bit of persisted state which you can manipulate and examine, but which cron cannot)

**be careful with time arithmetic if you're using human-readable clock time-- twice a year, some days have 23 or 25 hours in their day, and 02:00-02:59 occurs twice in one day or not at all.   Use UTC to avoid this.

Answer (score 30):

I don't think you have what you need with:

```
0 0 */3 * * ## <<< WARNING!!! CAUSES UNEVEN INTERVALS AT END OF MONTH!!
```

Unfortunately, the */3 is setting the interval on *every n day of the month* and **not** *every n days*. See: [explanation here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/3_*_*). At the end of the month there is recurring issue guaranteed.

```
1st  at 2019-02-01 00:00:00
then at 2019-02-04 00:00:00 << 3 days, etc. OK
then at 2019-02-07 00:00:00
...
then at 2019-02-25 00:00:00
then at 2019-02-28 00:00:00
then at 2019-03-01 00:00:00 << 1 day WRONG
then at 2019-03-04 00:00:00
...
```

According to [this article](https://backreference.org/2013/08/25/run-cron-job-every-n-days/), you need to add some modulo math to the command being executed to get a TRUE "every N days". For example:

```
0 0 * * *  bash -c '(( $(date +\%s) / 86400 \% 3 == 0 )) && runmyjob.sh'
```

In this example, the job will be checked daily at 12:00 AM, but will only execute when the number of days since 01-01-1970 modulo 3 is 0.

If you want it to be every 3 days from a specific date, use the following format:

```
0 0 * * *  bash -c '(( $(date +\%s -d "2019-01-01") / 86400 \% 3 == 0 )) && runmyjob.sh'
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Using `-d` combined with `+s` gives you the number of seconds that have elapsed from epoch to the date specified by `-d`.The arithmetic expression will always evaluate to be the same regardless of the current day.  A more accurate calculation is to use the `+s -d` variant as well as store the number of seconds that have elapsed since epoch (`+s`), then take the difference and divide by 86400 to get the number of days that have elapsed since the start date. You can apply a modulus operator after. To this person's credit, it is the most correct answer so far.

Answer (score 28):

I am not a cron specialist, but how about:

```
0 */72 * * *
```

It will run every 72 hours non-interrupted.

https://crontab.guru/#0_*/72_*_*_*

Comment: This is more accurate than the accepted solution. The accepted answer will fail when changing months: `then at 2019-02-28 00:00:00 then at 2019-03-01 00:00:00`

Comment: How does one calculate when this will occur?

Comment: According to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/72_*_*_*) this runs every day. Who is right?

Comment: The value in the hour column must fall between 0 and 23 according to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_%2A/72_%2A_%2A_%2A) and [man crontab](https://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html).

Comment: */72 is effectively the same as 0. This runs every midnight.

Comment: I tested this. It is running everyday.

Comment: this won't run every 3 days, but on next midnight and then every minute after it, at least by https://crontab.guru/#*_*/72_*_*_* (click on the "next" text)

Answer (score 11):

```
0 0 1-30/3 * *
```

This would run every three days starting 1st. Here are the 20 scheduled runs -

- 2015-06-01 00:00:00
- 2015-06-04 00:00:00
- 2015-06-07 00:00:00
- 2015-06-10 00:00:00
- 2015-06-13 00:00:00
- 2015-06-16 00:00:00
- 2015-06-19 00:00:00
- 2015-06-22 00:00:00
- 2015-06-25 00:00:00
- 2015-06-28 00:00:00
- 2015-07-01 00:00:00
- 2015-07-04 00:00:00
- 2015-07-07 00:00:00
- 2015-07-10 00:00:00
- 2015-07-13 00:00:00
- 2015-07-16 00:00:00
- 2015-07-19 00:00:00
- 2015-07-22 00:00:00
- 2015-07-25 00:00:00
- 2015-07-28 00:00:00

Comment: 2015-07-31 00:00:00, 2015-08-01 00:00:00...
OOPS only 1 day between runs

Comment: OOPS, it doesn't matter if it is only 1 day between runs.  The question specified, "Or maybe 10 times/month."  This answer achieves the goal of meeting one of the two criteria that could be used.  (If it sounds dumb to just ignore the possibility of running 2 days in a row, well, the fault is in the question, not the answer.  The question doesn't specify the scenario for how this information is going to be used.  It is right to answer the question as it is, in its current form.) 
 Upvoting answer which successfully provided a solution for what was actually requested.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
00 00  *  *   * every 3 days && echo test
```

Where `every` is a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $2 in
    days)
        expr `date +%j` % $1 = 0 > /dev/null
        ;;

    weeks)
        expr `date +%V` % $1 = 0 > /dev/null
        ;;

    months)
        expr `date +%m` % $1 = 0 > /dev/null
        ;;
esac
```

So it runs every day.

Using `*/3` runs on the 3rd, 6th, ... 27th, 30th of the month, but is then wrong after a month has a 31st day.  The `every` script is only wrong after the end of the year.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler if you configured it to just run e.g. on monday and thursdays, which would give it a 3 and 4 day break.

Otherwise configure it to run daily, but make your php cron script exit early with:

```
if (! (date("z") % 3)) {
     exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since UTC days are exactly 86400 seconds (all of them, forget about leap seconds, they don't affect UTC days), dividing (integer division) the epoch time in seconds by `86400` gives us (full) elapsed days since *epoch*. With some more math we may arrive to this cron line:

```
12 21 * * * [ $(( ($(date +\%s)/86400+0) \% 3 )) = 0 ]  && do_stuff
```

If today is `08/30/2021` at `New_York` the best time to execute the command is at `21:12` (or later) to ensure **full** days. At such time and date, the command will be executed. If there is the need to move the day, then change the `0` to an appropriate offset to get a `0-day` on that day.

It is also possible to use any other cycle `n` (instead of 3).

The result is **not** affected by month, year or century. There will always be a cycle of `n` days

Note that cron requires that the `%` are escaped as `\%`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want it to run on specific days of the month, like the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc... then you can just have a conditional in your script that checks for the current day of the month.

I thought all you needed for this was instead of */3 which means every three days, use 1/3 which means every three days starting on the 1st of the month. so 7/3 would mean every three days starting on the 7th of the month, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`0 0 * * * [ $(($((`date +%-j`- 1)) % 3)) == 0 ] && script`

Get the day of the year from `date`, offset by 1 to start at 0, check if it is modulo three.

Comment: Won't this hiccup when it rolls over from a non-leap year to the next year, since ``( 365-1 ) % 3 == 1`` but  ``( 1 - 1 ) % 3 == 0``? I would think the better calculation would be based on the number of days since the Unix Epoch.