# Automated recursive touch of all contents in current directory

Tags: linux, timer

I want to create a short automated script that will run automatically once every 10 days to recursively update all the files in my Linux system automatically without me having to run the script myself (i.e., update all file dates in all subdirectories of my current directory).  Here is what I've tried:

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
```

This command successfully updates all file creation dates to the current time and applies it to all contents from the current directory and any subdirectories within it.

Is there a way I can automate it now with an arbitrary timer command?  Kudos to anyone who can also show me how to make the script into a hidden file that I don't have to worry about on my system.

Comment: I can show you how to launch it automatically, but you will need to define what the current directory should be. It will be the current directory of the command, e.g. $HOME if launched with your account. Is it what you want ?

Comment: @MatM Yes, that should be reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cron** should be installed by default, else you can install it using your package manager.

`2/10` every 10 days **in the month** starting the 2nd (2nd, 12th, 22th)
`0 3` means 3:00 am. Update as you wish.
I choose the second because it avoids to run twic on the 31st and the 1st.

```
#minutes hours days months  days_of_week COMMAND
0 3 2/10 * * find $HOME -exec touch {} \;
```

In a terminal, do

```
crontab -e  # edit the scheduling
```

You will be in an editor (most certainly **vi**).
Paste the line containing the find and exit. Cron will check the syntax of the line (not of your command, though), and then load it in the daemon.

No script file is created.

**Note:** The 10 days is approximated each month. To get more tuning outside of the command, search for other schedulers.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to expand on "Paste the line containing the find and exit. Cron will check the syntax of the line (not of your command, though), and then load it in the daemon."

Comment: It was just some inner details about what will happen once you quit the editor. After saving the file, it will be given to the daemon to read. Daemon parses the line to find triggers and command, and add it to its spool and timers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron to do it every 10 days, as described in [Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days)

I don't know what you mean by "hidden" though

Comment: `ls -a` style or perhaps something more hidden (if that's even possible).  I don't want to see this file when I `ls -la` my files.

Comment: Well the crontab file isn't stored in your home directory, so it will be "hidden" in that sense at least--also, that means you'll want to change the path in your find I imagine.