# How to setup cron job to run every 5 days?

Tags: arrays, cron

I want to setup cronjob which will start on for example today and it will run every 5 days.
This is what I have now, is this will work correctly ? If I install this job at 5 o`clock and then every 5 days on 6 AM.

0 6 */5 * *  mailx -r root@mail.com -s "Message title" -c "cc@mail.com" primary@mail.com < body.txt

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
0 0 */5 * *  midnight every 5 days.
```

See this, similar question just asked for every 3 days.
[Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days)

Comment: So it will be send today at midnight and then on 11th midnight  ?

Comment: It will run on the first day on month too. So a run on 31 and on 1. In that case the difference is 1 day, not 5.

Answer (score 15):

Bear with me, this is my first time posting an answer... let me know if anything I put is unclear.

I don't think you have what you need with:

```
0 0 */5 * * ## <<< WARNING!!! CAUSES UNEVEN INTERVALS AT END OF MONTH!!
```

Unfortunately, the */5 is setting the interval based on day of the month. See: [explanation here](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/5_*_*). At the end of the month there is recurring issue guaranteed.

```
1st  at 2019-01-01 00:00:00
then at 2019-01-06 00:00:00 << 5 days, etc. OK
then at 2019-01-11 00:00:00
...
then at 2019-01-26 00:00:00
then at 2019-01-31 00:00:00
then at 2019-02-01 00:00:00 << 1 day WRONG
then at 2019-02-06 00:00:00
...
then at 2019-02-26 00:00:00
then at 2019-03-01 00:00:00 << 3 days WRONG
```

According to [this article](https://backreference.org/2013/08/25/run-cron-job-every-n-days/), you need to add some modulo math to the command being executed to get a TRUE "every N days". For example:

```
0 0 * * *  bash -c '(( $(date +\%s) / 86400 \% 5 == 0 )) && runmyjob.sh
```

In this example, the job will be checked daily at 12:00 AM, but will only execute when the number of days since 01-01-1970 modulo 5 is 0.

If you want it to be every 5 days from a specific date, use the following format:

```
0 0 * * *  bash -c '(( $(date +\%s -d "2019-01-01") / 86400 \% 5 == 0 )) && runmyjob.sh
```

Comment: in ```"2019-01-01"``` is the month second or last?

Answer (score 0):

The last snippet of Brad will not work because it ignores the actual date.

> date +%s -d "2019-01-01"

will always return the same amount of seconds which will end up in either always true or always false depending on which date you choose.

you would have to do an extra calculation like this to run it every 5 days at 00:00 from 2019-01-01 00:00:00 on:

```
0 0 * * * bash -c '(( ( $(date +\%s) - $(date +\%s -d "2019-01-01 00:00:00") ) / 86400 \% 5 == 0 )) && runmyjob.sh'
```