# How to create cron job that will run every n-th day in PHP?

Tags: php, cron

I'm pretty new to this subject, so I want to create `cron job` that runs every n number of days at 9 o'clock starting from current date. I've found similar question here: [Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days)
And according to it's answer code would look something like this(let's say I want to execute my script every 100 days):

```
exec("0 9 /100 * * /usr/local/bin/php path/to/php/file/phpfile.php ".escapeshellarg($notificationIdForCron)." &");
```

But I wonder, will this really execute my script every 100 days? Is syntax of this line of code according to what cron job expects, or do I need to break this 100 days into months or eventually years if number of days reaches beyond 365 days?

Comment: 3rd argument for cron is "day of the month"... and no month has more than 31 days

Comment: Yeah, I know that and that's why I asked last qustion. So, I need to break this number of days into month-year sequences?

Comment: Easiest is to have the cron running daily, and then a check at the top of the code for the last date it fully executed, and check if that was >= 100 days ago

Comment: Yeah, that would be smart. Thanks!