# What is the most reliable way to schedule a job with cron scheduler is Quartz that repeats every N days starting from a specific date

Tags: scala, cron, quartz-scheduler, dst

In our app, we have an ability to schedule tasks and we converting this functionality to Quartz. One of the problems that I have is scheduling recurring task that should run, for example, every third day.
The cron expression that I had in mind first of all is:

> 0 37 18 */3 * ? *

But what this will do, is execute that job on 1,4,7, etc... Which is fine, assuming that I want to start from the first day of the month. However, how to deal with this issue if I need to start from 11th?
I could do something like this:

> 0 37 18 11/3 * ? *

But, in this case, I will always miss all the days before the 11th.

Also, when the time comes for the next month, the expectation that the day of the month will now be different (on one month the job executed on 1st, and on another it could be on 2/3), but based on the cron above it will restart on the same day (e.g. 1st).

I could, of course, count using hours, but then I will have an issue with day light saving?

What is the correct way to organize it? Or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
Possible solution is to use simple trigger, as per http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger.
But in this case, how do I resolve DST problem?

Thanks,

Comment: this question has been asked before, is this solution suitable? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31698862/6449675

Comment: I've seen this one, and it's tempting, but given that we using Quartz it is extremely hard to achieve this within quartz's architecture.

Comment: `CalendarIntervalTrigger` described on the same page you linked to does exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Isn't it still calculates everything based on N milliseconds, but you basically set it in a different way?

Comment: No, it's based on _calendar_.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try