# Cron job every four days

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

Is it possible to run a cronjob every four days using Laravel? Without relying on each month.

Check the schedule command below

```
$schedule->command('file:backup')->daily();
```

Cron does not depend on the months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days)

Answer (score 1):

Following the **Laravel Documentation** may be like this:

```
$schedule->command('file:backup')->cron('0 0 */4 * *');
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$schedule->command('file:backup')->('0 0 */4 * *');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

```
$schedule->command('file:backup')->cron('0 0 */4 * *');
```