# Is there any way to schedule job every N day without missing days using 0 0 1-31/N * * Cron expression?

Tags: c#, cron

I am passing cron expression to run jobs at every N days, which seems to be missing days as my expression is incomplete!

```
0 0 1-31/N * *
```

I want my expression to be consistent and should not be missing days in a month.

For example:

Expression `0 0 1-31/3 * *` for date `28/10/2019` will be giving `31/10/2019` as result and next day in iteration should be `3/11/2019`, but it gives `1/11/2019` as days in expression is specified between 1-31.

Comment: this question is very similar with [cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days). however, there is known problem when using `0 0 */3 * *` that end of month will cause problem and the mitigation is adding day checks on the code that being run by the cron.

Comment: @BagusTesa that will definitely make the code unnecessary complicated & ugly. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: i know it will be ugly, but... guess nothing else really works.