# Hangfire daily execution schedule

Tags: hangfire

By default the daily schedule always starts the interval from the start of the month.
But I don’t want this behavior.

Rather, I want a job to start on the date I set and consider the interval from that date onwards and not from the start of the month.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific with examples? Is the _interval_ you refer to always a calendar month, ore can it be something like every 13 days?

Comment: The Interval can be in days. let's say I want to start the hangfire job execution from today i.e. 31st August and then the job should execute on every 4th day now onward. (4 days interval). In this case the execution cycle needs to be 31, 4, 8, 12 and so on.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do you have answer?

Comment: Here's a cron expression for every three days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days. If this works in hangfire please post a full example as an answer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry...  This is not what I want. The interval always starts from 1st of the month in this case. I want interval to start from the date I want.

Comment: There's a lot of different answers in that thread.