# How to set airflow cron for run once every 72 hours?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

`0 */3 * * *` will run every day, and `0 0 */3 * *` will reset when month changed.

I want it to run once every 72 hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days)

Answer (score 0):

> 'schedule_interval': timedelta(hours=72)

For testing I have executed a sample dag with below code and this is the outcome is in the screenshot.

```
 import datetime as dt

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_latest_only',
    schedule_interval=dt.timedelta(minutes=4),
    start_date=dt.datetime(2020,12,25),
    tags=['example'],
    catchup=False
)

latest_only = DummyOperator(task_id='latest_only', dag=dag)
task1 = DummyOperator(task_id='task1', dag=dag)

latest_only >> task1
```

[image]

Comment: It won't work, as this returns you an object which is `NOW() + 3 days` - basically each time scheduler would check schedule of the dag it will see **this** `NOW() + 3 days`, which will never occur. Having said that, cron expression must be used as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days