# How to schedule job on Oozie every exactly n day regardless of the month

Tags: cron, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I would like to schedule a job to run every `n` day where n is not 1 or 7. I know the syntax `0 0 */n * *`, but when I check for the next execution dates, it always runs on 1st of the next month, regardless of the `n` day interval from the last month's run. Hence, the interval is not exactly `n` days. How can I properly schedule this case?

Here is the example of this problem where it will execute two days consecutively if it the date is near the end of the month. [image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549542/cron-job-every-three-days and look at answer for every 72 hours using 0 */72 * * * , adjust for your n days.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the related question. In the comment below it said it will end up running every day at midnight for the hour-based pattern. [crontab.guru/#0_*/72_*_*_*](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/72_*_*_*)

Comment: I see that now that I look closer, sorry it didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Start a script every day via cron.  That script makes the calculations of delays and starts the other script on days that are good.  cron is date based, the case you want cannot be done with cron syntax (AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you @Nic3500. This question should be applied to Oozie as well. That's the part that I cannot think of a good solution. It is a simple question that I'm wondering why I can't find a solution to despite having been used for years.