# Run a cron job exactly every 89 days

Tags: cron

There is a need to run the script once every 89 days. I know how to do it every three months "* * */3 * * command
", but once every three months it's not every 89 days, because 3 months - from 90 to 92 days, but how to run exactly once every 89 days, please tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron job every three days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4549542/11683)